# JQuery .show() is only working in first page of a table with JQuery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a `<select>` in a `<td>` of a DataTable like this:

```
<td><select class="cambioEstado">
      <option style="display:none;" value="14" class="opcion4">L4</option>
      <option style="display:none;" value="15" class="opcion5">L5</option>
</select></td>
```

When i press a button, i change the options display with .show():

```
$(".btn4").live("click", function(){
     $(".opcion4").show();
});
```

But this only work fine for the first page, when i go to second page, the button must be pressed again to show "opcion4".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem using an array to save the state of each option, and restore the state using a `fnDrawCallback` function of datatable.

`fnDrawCallback` is fired when change a page.

```
var estadoListados = new Array();
$(".btn4").live("click", function(){
     $(".opcion4").show();
     estadoListados[4] = "abierto";
});

var optionDT = {
                    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
                      "fnDrawCallback": function() {
                                for (x=0;x<estadoListados.length;x++){
                                if(estadoListados[x]==="abierto"){
                                    $(".opcion"+x).show();
                                }
                                 if(estadoListados[x]==="cerrado"){
                                    $(".opcion"+x).hide();
                                }
                                }
                      },
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",   
                    "iDisplayLength": 25,
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sUrl": "../js/bootstrap/datatables/media/language/dataTables.spanish.txt"
                    }
                };


            $(document).ready(function() {
                oTable=$(".dataTable").dataTable(optionDT);               
            } );
```